# Null longitud y latitud al querer obtenerlas

Tags: java, android

Tengo una clase en donde se supone que se obtiene la longitud y latitud pero al momento de querer obtenerla desde mi servicio, me la manda en 0.0 he buscado las respuestas que me dan no funcionan aquí el código.

GPSTracker.java

```
package com.android.controlmovil.funciones;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

/**
 * Create this Class from tutorial :
 * http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial
 *
 * For Geocoder read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472313/android-reverse-geocoding-getfromlocation
 *
 */

public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private final Context mContext;

    // Flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // Flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    // Flag for GPS status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location; // Location
    double latitude; // Latitude
    double longitude; // Longitude
    LocationServices locationserice;
    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;

    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // Getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // Getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // No network provider is enabled
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    checkLocationPermission();
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                };
                // If GPS enabled, get latitude/longitude using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }


    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener
     * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app.
     * */


    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     * */
    public double getLatitude(){
        if(location != null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }


    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     * */
    public double getLongitude(){
        if(location != null){
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to check GPS/Wi-Fi enabled
     * @return boolean
     * */
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }


    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog.
     * On pressing the Settings button it will launch Settings Options.
     * */
    public void showSettingsAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // On pressing the Settings button.
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // On pressing the cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }


    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }


    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }


    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    public boolean checkLocationPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Mi servicio donde quiero obtenerlas

```
public void comenzarLocalizacion(Context mcontext) {


        GPSTracker gps = new GPSTracker(mcontext);

        if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
            latitud = gps.getLatitude();
            longitud = gps.getLongitude();

            Log.e("Latitud",">>"+latitud);
            Log.e("Latitud",">>"+latitud);

            try{
                Toast.makeText(enviar_coord_background.this,"Coordenadas Enviadas",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }catch (Exception e){

            }
        } else {
            latitud = 0.0;
            longitud = 0.0;
        }
    }
```

Obtengo valores de 0.0 y ya agregué los siguientes permisos a mi Manifest.xml

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
```

Comment: Carlos, revisa si esto se esta cumpliendo, if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {   . debes revisar si ambos proveedores no estan activos. me comentas que resultado tienes.

Comment: Si se cumple esa líne de código, en realidad no encontré como solucionarlo y obté por utilizar otro código y me funciono :)

Comment: Deberias de publicar el codigo que te funciono, tengo el mismo o muy parecido problema, podrias hacerlo? Gracias!

Comment: @Carlos, ya que has encontrado una solución, podrías publicarla como respuesta a tu pregunta, para que otras personas con problemas similares tengan una alternativa.

Comment: claro puedes probar este ejemplo es mucho mas sencillo, https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/location/android-location-based-services-example/

Answer (score 1):

Debido a que este código en su mayoría causa error a muchas personas, encontré una manera de obtener la longitud, latitud y lo adapté de acuerdo a mis necesidades en
https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/location/android-location-based-services-example/

**activity_main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="Do you want a fine accuracy or not?" />

     <TextView
            android:id="@+id/choice"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="coarse accuracy selected (default)" />

     <CheckBox
         android:id="@+id/fineAccuracy"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="fine accuracy" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/chooseRadio"
         style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="OK" />

      <TextView
            android:id="@+id/prov"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="No provider selected yet"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lat"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Latitude: -"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Longitude: -"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**:

```
package com.javacodegeeks.android.locationservicetest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
      private TextView latitude;
      private TextView longitude;
      private TextView choice;
      private CheckBox fineAcc;
      private Button choose;
      private TextView provText;
      private LocationManager locationManager;
      private String provider;
      private MyLocationListener mylistener;
      private Criteria criteria;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          latitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lat);
          longitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lon);
          provText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.prov);
          choice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.choice);
          fineAcc = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.fineAccuracy);
          choose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.chooseRadio);

          // Get the location manager
          locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
          // Define the criteria how to select the location provider
          criteria = new Criteria();
          criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);   //default

          // user defines the criteria
          choose.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 if(fineAcc.isChecked()){
                      criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
                      choice.setText("fine accuracy selected");
                 }else {
                     criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
                     choice.setText("coarse accuracy selected");
                 }  
            }
          });
          criteria.setCostAllowed(false); 
          // get the best provider depending on the criteria
          provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

          // the last known location of this provider
          Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

          mylistener = new MyLocationListener();

          if (location != null) {
              mylistener.onLocationChanged(location);
          } else {
              // leads to the settings because there is no last known location
              Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
              startActivity(intent);
          }
          // location updates: at least 1 meter and 200millsecs change
          locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 200, 1, mylistener);
      }

      private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

          @Override
          public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // Initialize the location fields
              latitude.setText("Latitude: "+String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
              longitude.setText("Longitude: "+String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
              provText.setText(provider + " provider has been selected.");

              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,  "Location changed!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }

          @Override
          public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, provider + "'s status changed to "+status +"!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }

          @Override
          public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Provider " + provider + " enabled!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          }

          @Override
          public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Provider " + provider + " disabled!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
      }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.javacodegeeks.android.locationservicetest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.javacodegeeks.android.locationservicetest.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Edité la pregunta agregando el código del enlace. Esto se recomienda para que las respuestas estén completas en el sitio (sabiendo que el enlace podría no estar disponible en el futuro)... Además, podrías aceptar esta respuesta haciendo click en el **✅** a la izquierda.

Comment: Gracias Mariano, no lo sabía, pero de ahora en adelante lo tomaré en cuenta cuando quiera compartir código de un enlace ;) Y no me permite aceptar la respuesta hasta dos días me aparece D: